# How to parse apt no from the address field in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I NEED TO EXTRACT LAST NUMBER IN THE DATA AS APTNO?

[enter image description here][1]

My data in the below picture. I m almost there to get my results but i want the number and also when there is APt i want number with APT as well

Comment: Do all addresses have apartment/suite numbers at the end? What have you tried so far and what problems have you run into?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a **minimal reproducible example**. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One more method based on JSON.

It will work starting from SQL Server 2016 onwards.

**SQL Server 2016**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens VARCHAR(250));  
INSERT Into @tbl (tokens) VALUES 
('250 Cambridge ST 305'),
('30 ACKERS AVE 2');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @Word INT = 4;
SELECT * 
    , token = JSON_VALUE('["' +
        REPLACE(REPLACE(tokens
            ,'"','\"')
            ,' ','","') +
        '"]', CONCAT('$[', @Word-1,']'))
FROM @tbl ;
```

**SQL Server 2008 onwards**

XML/XQuery based method. Useful when number of tokens fluctuates (or unknown) for each row.

```
DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = SPACE(1);
SELECT * 
    , TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
    REPLACE(tokens, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
    ']]></r></root>' AS XML).value('(/root/r[last()]/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(30)') AS token
FROM @tbl;
```

**Output**

```
+----+----------------------+-------+
| ID |        tokens        | token |
+----+----------------------+-------+
|  1 | 250 Cambridge ST 305 |   305 |
|  2 | 30 ACKERS AVE 2      |     2 |
+----+----------------------+-------+
```

Comment: but i still this is not working as what i wanted ,, i just wanted to get Apt number and any time we have accronym APT then it should get everything there

Comment: @sindhurilokesh, As I mentioned earlier, you need to provide **a minimal reproducible example.** All the ##1-4. When it is done. I can reopen your post.

Comment: This code helped me but i still achieve my exact results

Comment: @sindhurilokesh, Again, edit your question, put there ##1-4. And I will help you to get exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

For your examples, you can use `string_split()`:

```
select t.*, s.value as the_number
from t cross apply
     (select top (1) s.value
      from string_split(t.address, ' ') s
      where s.value not like '%[^0-9]%' 
      order by charindex(' ' + s.value + ' ', ' ' + t.address + ' ') desc
     ) s
```

Answer (score 1):

Gordon's answer works great for SQL 2016 and up. For older versions, this could work.

```
SELECT  t.Address
        ,REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(t.Address), CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(t.Address), 0))) AS ApartmentNum
FROM    Table AS t;
```

Comment: Thank you for your time this code didnt work